# Ionic 2: How can I force cache pages?

Tags: ionic2

I love how the cached pages are fast in Ionic 2, but the first load is always slow. Is there a way I could force cache creation of a page (for example during the Splash, before the platform ready, etc) ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant preload a page before it has already been created. What you can do is preload data from the app.componant.ts page like [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts#L74-76)

Then push your data on viewWillEnter

```
viewWillEnter(){

}
```